# iOS: remove objects or reinitialize arrays in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm new in swift and I want to know if the beast approach to reuse an array is to delete all object inside or reinitialize it.

For example if I have:

```
var my_array:NSMutableArray! //global variable
```

and the first method that I use:

```
func firstMethod{
    my_array = NSMutableArray()
    my_array.addObject("one")
    my_array.addObject("two")
    my_array.addObject("three")
    ...
}
```

for example now in another method I need my_array empty:

the best solution is this:

```
func newmethod() {
    my_array = NSMutableArray() //reinitialize (drastic method)
    //here, all new operation with my_array
}
```

or is this?:

```
func newmethod() {
    if my_array == nil{
        my_array = NSMutableArray()
    } else {
        my_array.removeAllObjects()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to reinitialise the array again. You can remove the old objects and use this array to add new ones. So the second approach work fine in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are reinitializing the array there is no need to reinitialize it.And if you reinitialize then it will point to another memory address so it would be better to reuse without reinitialize. You can do like this

```
if (my_array == nil){
            my_array = NSMutableArray();
        }
        else{
            //my_array.removeAllObjects();
            // Do your stuff here
        }
```

Comment: yes thanks, I did this in obj-c, but I didn't know if in swift was the same... but it's ok thanks

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is *it depends*.  There is a really major danger when it comes to having mutable public properties, particularly when it comes to multithreaded apps.

If you always reinitialize, it is more likely that you're safe from multithreading issues.

If you are emptying the array, you are prone multithreading issues.  You're probably going to get index out of bounds crashes and the like when you are emptying the array on one thread and trying to access *any* index on another thread.

> Thread A check's the array's count.  It's 10. Thread B empties the
>   array.  Array's count is now 0. Thread A tries to access an object at
>   index 3.  Crash.

Even though your code looks fine, something like this:

```
if array.count > 3 {
    array[3].doThings()
}
```

Multithreading means that another thread mutating the array between that code checking the count and that code accessing an index.

I would opt for immutable objects as much as possible, and I would avoid mutating mutable objects that have any chance of being accessed in a thread unsafe manner.